# Storing converted value in a Variable

Tags: c#

I am trying to store the value of an extracted string..I can't get it to work

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string a = "123";

            int c = a[a.Length - 1];

            Console.WriteLine(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Shouldn't 3 be stored in the variable c? I want only 3 to be stored; I don't know what's wrong with this, the output is '51' how's that possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Shouldn't 3 be stored in the variable c?

No, the integer representation of `'3'` should be stored in the variable `c`, and indeed is.

You're effectively doing:

```
char tmp = a[a.Length - 1]; // tmp = '3'
int c = tmp; // Implicit conversion to int
```

The "character" representation in .NET is really a UTF-16 code unit... and converting from `char` to `int` just copies that code unit.

The code unit for `'3'` is 51, hence your output.

If you just use `char` instead, you'll be fine:

```
string a = "123";
char c = a[a.Length - 1];
Console.WriteLine(c); // "3"
```

If you want to get the "numeric value" of a character, you can use [`char.GetNumericValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7k33ktz(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
int value = (int) char.GetNumericValue(a[a.Length - 1]);
```

Note that you have to cast to `int` because the return type is `double`, in order to cope with characters representing fractions, infinity etc.

If you're *absolutely sure* that the value is always an ASCII digit, you can just subtract `'0'`:

```
int value = a[a.Length - 1] - '0';
```

Just be aware that that will silently give "odd" results for non-digit input though.

Comment: Thanks a lot; but is there a way through which I could to that without converting to char? actually I want to add a Number with that 3, and If i will convert to char i won't be able to add..

Comment: @user3497152: You've *got* a `char` - a string is a sequence of `char` values, basically. So that's what you've started with... you're not converting *to* `char`. What you want is apparently to convert *from* `char` to `int` - see the end of my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are implicitily converting the ascii code of the character 3 to an integer.
This code value is 51

If you want to get the integer value you need to parse that character

```
string a = "123";

char c = a[a.Length - 1];
string c2 = string.Concat(c,c);
int v = Int32.Parse(c.ToString());
int v2 = v + v;

Console.WriteLine("This is a char:" + c);   // 3
Console.WriteLine("This is a string:" + c2); // 33
Console.WriteLine("This is an integer: " + v);  // 3
Console.WriteLine("This is an integer: " + v2);  // 6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use implicit conversion between a char and integer

or

use the explicit conversion from string to int using [Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string a ="123";
string b = a.Substring(a.Length-1,1);
int c = int.Parse(b);
```